# Java Akka concurrent limitation in using router?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, akka, akka-cluster

The code is:

```
public class TestAkka {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ExampleRouter", ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("MyRouter"));
        ActorRef router = system.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class).withRouter(new FromConfig()), "exampleRouter");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            router.tell(new Website().getNameByIndex(i), router);
        }
    }

    public static class Hello extends UntypedActor {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
            if (message instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + message);
                URL url = new URL("http://" + message + ":80");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
                Thread.sleep(10000);  // <-- Sim the job take a short time
            } else {
                unhandled(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The application.conf is:

```
MyRouter{
    akka {
        actor {
            deployment {
                /exampleRouter {
                    router = round-robin-pool
                    nr-of-instances = 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is that I can just see 8 concurrent jobs are running every time, but my expectation is 100 concurrent jobs should run at the same time! it is still require any settings?

UPDATED at 2016/06/06:
I have modified my code and the result is my expectation with overrided the application.conf, it can run 100 concurrent jobs at the same time now. In fact, how to optimize default-dispatcher for high concurrent application?

```
String s = ""
        + "akka {\n"
        + "    actor {\n"
        + "        deployment {\n"
        + "            /router {\n"
        + "                router = round-robin-pool\n"
        + "                nr-of-instances = 10000\n"
        + "            }\n"
        + "        }\n"
        + "        default-dispatcher {\n"
        + "            fork-join-executor {\n"
        + "                parallelism-min = 200\n"
        + "                parallelism-max = 5000\n"
        + "            }\n"
        + "        }\n"
        + "    }\n"
        + "}\n";
ActorSystem as = ActorSystem.create("as", ConfigFactory.parseString(s));
ActorRef ar = as.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class).withRouter(new FromConfig()), "router");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting confused between number of actors and dispatcher threads:

- Number of actors in a router: it's the number of instances created in memory that will handle the messages coming to the router following the selected logic.
- Dispatcher threads: A dispatcher is a thread pool (or executor service) that is responsible for managing threads to get messages from the actor mailboxes and execute the `receive` method.

The maximum number of concurrent tasks happening in your system will be limited by the dispatcher configuration. Having routers (and therefore more actors to process messages) will let those messages to be processed concurrently by the threads in the dispatcher.

I would recommend reading more about the akka dispatchers and in particular about the default dispatcher: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html

Comment: I have a question that the parameter thoughtput=100 in application.conf, what is the actual usage to use 100 or 1? what condition can use 1 or 100? In fact, I am not so understand the document, as there are no actul examples to explain it.

Comment: I do not understand what some examples set thoughtput=100, how can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `Thread.sleep` blocks the thread, so you're running out of threads. If you want to see all 100 of them you should run the blocking operations on their own dedicated threads.

Comment: The code inside Thread.sleep is to use to sim the job that takes a long time to execute, so that's why I added it!!